# NodeJS: Mocha+Selenium tests with promises fail on Travis (succeed on local)

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, travis-ci

I'm doing automated Mocha testing with Selenium WebDriver on Travis. If I just run the test synchronously and call `done()` at the end, the tests pass beautifully. As soon as I introduce async behavior (ie. `.then(function(){... done()})`, Travis tests fail, although locally they still run as they're supposed to.

For example:

```
describe('Map load test', function() {
    let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('firefox')
        .build();
    this.timeout(60000);

    beforeEach(function(done) {
        console.log('beforeEach');
        driver.get(index).then(function() {
            console.log('Loaded index');
            done();
        });
    });

    after(function() {
        console.log('after');
        driver.quit();
    });

    it('Should load the choropleth demo without issues', function(done) {
        console.log('Starting Choropleth test');
        driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
            assert.equal(url, index, 'Initial url did not match');
            console.log('loaded' + url);
            driver.findElement(By.css('#demo0')).click();
            driver.findElement(By.css('.loadDemoButton')).click();
            driver.sleep(3000);
            console.log('slept for 3000');
            driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
                assert.equal(url, index + '#edit', 'File loaded url did not match');
                done();
            });
        });

    });
```

Results in (Note - doesn't even go into the actual test but fails on beforeEach)

```
Map load test

beforeEach

    1) "before each" hook for "Should load the choropleth demo without issues"

after

  0 passing (1m)

  1 failing

  1) Map load test "before each" hook for "Should load the choropleth demo without issues":

     Error: Timeout of 60000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

But doing

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
        console.log('beforeEach');
        driver.get(index).then(done());
    });
```

continues on to the next test.

Travis.yml:

```
language: node_js
env:
  - CXX=g++-5
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
    packages:
      - g++-5
node_js:
 - "7.6.0"
before_install:
  - wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.14.0/geckodriver-v0.14.0-linux64.tar.gz
  - mkdir geckodriver
  - tar -xzf geckodriver-v0.14.0-linux64.tar.gz -C geckodriver
  - export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/geckodriver
```

[The test file](https://github.com/simopaasisalo/MakeMaps/blob/master/app/test/test_loads.ts)

[Failing Travis build logs](https://travis-ci.org/simopaasisalo/MakeMaps/builds)

Thanks for any suggestions. Debugging Travis failures is such a PITA...

Comment: I can't see the build logs (404). Try restarting the build and ssh'ing in, then going a step at a time.

Comment: @meatspace: I updated the link, should work okay now. Never done any SSH'ing on Travis but will give it a look, thanks!

Comment: this might be your problem: lack of C++11 compliant compiler. This build is using the Precise image (check build info), and read this: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs#Node.js-v4-(or-io.js-v3)-compiler-requirements)

Comment: @meatspace unfortunately that didn't work either, still getting the same error. [Full log of most recent failure](https://api.travis-ci.org/jobs/211239355/log.txt?deansi=true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some help I managed to get it working, though I'm still not sure exactly why. The key was adding xvfb to travis.yml:

```
language: node_js

addons:
  firefox: "51.0.1"

node_js:
 - "7.6.0"

before_script:
  - "export DISPLAY=:99.0"
  - "sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start"
  - sleep 3 # give xvfb some time to start
```